# get-aduser -ldapfilter with -OR

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search for multiple account extensions.

These work individually:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(name=*.ca)" | select name
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(name=*.da)" | select name
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(name=*.sa)" | select name
```

I'd like to search for all 3 account extensions with one script.
The next line doesn't work, however I think you'll see what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(name=*.ca)" -or "(name=*.da)" -or "(name=*.sa)" | select name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using -LDAPFilter you need to pass it a pure ldap filter string, the ldap logical or is |.

Try this:

```
 Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(|(name=*.ca)(name=*.da)(name=*.sa))" | select name
```